# How to set the default audio recorder application?

Tags: default

I installed the tool `audio-recorder` doing this:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```

Now how can you set it up as default audio recorder for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the application works? If so, you should not ask "how to install" but "how to set as default"

Comment: Yes. It works but how can I set it as default.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Hi. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Install `pavucontrol` (Pulse Audio Volume Control) using apt-get
2. Open it (should be in the Sound and Video category)
3. Go to the Recording tab
4. Select the "Applications" drop down menu
5. Look for the "Record from" menu and select `audio-recorder`

Comment: Hi. It says this 'package pavucontrol is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source'

Comment: I think that means you already have Pulse installed. Type "Audio" or "Mixer" in the Unity dash and you should find it.